# Retain Duplicates in MySQL Results

Tags: mysql

My query looks like this with four numbers:

```
select * from accounts where number in (000208,000208,001106,001110);
```

and the results I'm getting look like this with three numbers, which makes sense because 000208 is in there twice:

```
number id
000208 904
001106 574
001110 1580
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way to get these results:

```
number id
000208 904
000208 904
001106 574
001110 1580
```

Everything I can find is about removing duplicates from tables and results, but I can't find anything about this scenario.

Comment: You could `UNION` it with `select * from accounts where number in (000208)`

Comment: Why would you need same data multiple times? You can easily do that via extracting record in a code resultset. And can display or access it multiple times by storing in a variable. So what is its use case?

Comment: Did you try with no duplicate in IN()? Like IN (000208,001106,001110) ?

Comment: There is no difference between `000208` and `208`. There is however a difference between `'000208'` and `'208'`. And you're confusing data storage and retrieval with data display

Comment: @theonlynewts , can u please post your table schema?

Comment: I went the temp table route. The "number" in the query is coming from a csv that has several more columns and I'm matching data from the database to the csv where the "number" exists more than once.
I only have read rights to this database, so I was trying to avoid the temp table route, but my database admin had time to hook me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use temp tables

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ids;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids 
( 
 `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  number INTEGER, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO ids (number) VALUES (1),(1),(2);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM ids i
  LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.number = i.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
select a.*
from (select 000208 as number union all
      select 000208 union all
      select 001106 union all
      select 001110
     ) n left jion
     accounts a
     on n.number = a.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same item twice in your `IN` clause means nothing.

this query:

```
select * from accounts where number in (000208,000208,001106,001110);
```

is exactly like this one:

```
select * from accounts where number in (000208,001106,001110);
```

The way you'll get the same result twice does not depend on the query, but on the data inside the table- if you have it twice in your table (assuming the table allows duplication's), you will get it twice, either with `000208` once or twice in the query

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this
One is presented below using UNION to generate the required rows, the second option is by creating temporary tables and joining with that

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 000208 AS number
  UNION ALL SELECT 000208
  UNION ALL SELECT 001106
  UNION ALL SELECT 001110
) a1 ON accounts.number = a1.number
```